# Flutter: Weird errors encountered while generating apk - how to fix?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Hello I'm beginner in flutter when I try to build my project got an weird error

Try to build an apk but got some weird errors using Flutter stable version any body please look into and provide me solution ,

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: taxi_driver
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.1 <3.0.0"


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5

  chewie: 1.5.0

  # TOAST
  fluttertoast: 8.1.2

  # IMAGE
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3

  # BASE
  intl: ^0.18.0
  google_fonts: ^4.0.4
  html: ^0.15.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.17
  flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.9.1


  # UI
  sliding_up_panel: ^2.0.0+1
  dotted_line: ^3.1.0
  lottie: ^2.2.0
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.1
  flutter_staggered_animations: ^1.1.1
  bottom_picker: ^2.0.1
  country_code_picker: ^2.0.2
  flutter_native_contact_picker: ^0.0.3
  timeline_tile: ^2.0.0
  flutter_vector_icons: ^2.0.0
  flutter_switch: ^0.3.2
  syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^20.4.44

  #OTP TEXTFIELD
  otp_text_field: ^1.1.3

  # MAP
  geolocator: ^9.0.2
  geocoding: ^2.0.5
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.3
  flutter_polyline_points: ^1.0.0
  location: ^4.4.0

  # IMAGES
  image_picker: ^0.8.6+1
  file_picker: ^5.2.5
  date_time_picker: ^2.1.0

  # CONNECTIVITY
  package_info_plus: ^3.0.2


  # CONNECTIVITY
  http: ^0.13.5
  connectivity_plus: ^3.0.2
  url_launcher: ^6.1.8

  #FIREBASE
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.0.11
  firebase_core: ^2.4.1
  firebase_auth: ^4.2.5
  firebase_storage: ^11.0.10
  firebase_database: ^10.0.9
  paginate_firestore: ^1.0.3+1
  cloud_firestore: ^4.3.1

  # STATE MANAGEMENT
  mobx: ^2.1.3
  flutter_mobx: ^2.0.6+5

  # Payment gateway
  razorpay_flutter: ^1.3.4
  flutter_stripe: ^3.0.0
  flutter_paystack: ^1.0.7
  flutter_braintree: ^2.3.1
  flutterwave_standard: ^1.0.6
  flutter_paytabs_bridge: ^2.3.2
  mercado_pago_mobile_checkout: ^0.2.0-dev.3
  my_fatoorah: ^3.2.0
  paytm: ^3.0.1


  # PUSH NOTIFICATION
  onesignal_flutter: ^3.5.0

  # Social Login
  google_sign_in: ^5.4.3

  # MQTT
  mqtt_client: ^9.7.4

  # DOWNLOAD INVOICE PDF
  pdf: ^3.8.4
  path_provider: ^2.0.12
  open_file: ^3.2.1
  printing: ^5.9.3

  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  build_runner: ^2.3.3
  mobx_codegen: ^2.1.1
  #flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_core_platform_interface: ^4.5.2
  intl: ^0.18.0
  package_info_plus: ^3.0.2
  ffi: ^2.0.1
  open_file: 3.2.1
  cloud_firestore: ^4.3.1

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
      - images/
      - images/icons/
      - images/flag/
```

[image]

Comment: Please update `chewie` to 1.5.0, and post your `pubspe.yaml` if it is still an issue.

Comment: check I post pubspe.yaml

Comment: Which Flutter is used, please use the latest stable one.

Comment: flutter stable version is used

Comment: The build indicates that it's using `chewie: 1.0.0`. I would recommend running `flutter pub get` and attempting to perform the rebuild again. The `pubspec.lock` file and the `pubspec.yaml` files are out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and this steps solve the problem :

- Delete "pubspec.lock" file then run "flutter pub get".
- Update the kotlin version in "android/build.gradle" =>
  ext.kotlin_version =